# Class not found when creating model

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hey guys I'm new in Zend Framework. 
I'm trying to create a connection and get the rows of a table, I make this in  bootstrap.php

```
$this->bootstrap('db');
$m_routes = new Apartat() ;
```

It returns me this error: Fatal error: Class 'Apartat' not found in
I'm trying to follow ZF quickstart but I'm lost

1. I make models/Apartat.php

   ```
   <?php

   class Application_Model_Apartat
   {
   protected $_comment;
   protected $_created;
   protected $_email;
   protected $_id;

   }
   ```
2. I make models/ApartatMapper.php

   ```
   <?php

   class Application_Model_ApartatMapper
   {
   }
   ```
3. I make models/DbTabe/Apartat.php

   ```
   <?php

   class Application_Model_DbTable_Guestbook extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
   {
       protected $_name = 'guestbook';
   }
   ```

Previously I defined the connection parameters in application.ini

What else do I need? or what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class name is `Application_Model_Apartat` so you have to write

```
$m_routes = new Application_Model_Apartat() ;
```